# Uncompress using tar -xvzf results in a folder with less size than compressed file

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I have a file called DW.tar.gz in a RHEL 6 which has a size 539MB. But when it is uncompressed using: `tar xzvf DW.tar.gz` the resultant folder only has 44KB. The linux shell doesn't display any error or information. I don't understand why folder has less size than compressed file size (`ls -ltrh .`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you measure size of directory? Is it coming from some graphical file browser? If yes, then try to measure it from command line directrly like this:

`du -skh /path/to/dir`

Comment: `ls -ltrh` displays 44KB.
`du -skh` displays 8GB.
What is the difference between them?

Comment: @Franb Good news! You files are fine.
The issue you have is that `ls` shows size of directory entry itself (which is also a file), not the sum of files that it contain. `du` shows real size recursively.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why folder has less size than compressed file size

Youy already answered yourself. ls returned the size of the **folder** itself. Not the size of the file content in the folder. This of it as getting the size of a books index, which may be one or two pages even though the book and the stories in it are much longer.